# android edittext remove focus after clicking a button

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an Activity with an EditText and a Button.
When the User clicks on the EditText, the keyboard is shown and he can type in some Text - fine. 
But when the user clicks on the Button I want the EditText to be no more in focus i.e. the keyboard hides til the user clicks again on the EditText.

What can I do to 'hide the focus' of the EditText, after the Button is clicked. 
Some Code I can add in the OnClick Method of the Button to do that?

EDIT:

```xml
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edt_SearchDest"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:hint="Enter your look-up here.." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_SearchDest"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="Search" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Best Regards

Comment: clear the focus of Edittext on click of the button using `m_editText.clearFocus();`

Comment: didn't solved the issue.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Put this in your button listener:

```java
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

**EDIT**

The solution above will break your app if no `EditText` is focused on. Modify your code like this:

add this method to you class:

```java
public static void hideSoftKeyboard (Activity activity, View view) 
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Then, in your button listener, call the method like this:

```java
hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this, v); // MainActivity is the name of the class and v is the View parameter used in the button listener method onClick.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the only solution that has worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

One workaround is to create a fake view to transfer focus to when you `clearFocus` in your `edittext`:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_thief"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Note that this view is invisible so it doesn't require any space in the layout.

In the control class, you can add a method like the following to trigger this focus transfer:

```
public void clearFocus(){
        yourEdittext.clearFocus();
        edtThief.requestFocus();
    }
```

You can then minimize the keyboard once `edtThief` has focus:

```
 public static void hideKeyboard(final View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and I've ended up with a solution similar to this, in my case I had to request focus on the hidden view first and then clear focus,

Comment: One other thing that's very important on the EditText layout dont forget the           `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` so when you rotate the phone you don't get the edit text edit screen extracted.

Comment: this worked for me, the above accepted solution did not. I have multiple edittexts that i need to make sure lose focus when a button is clicked, so in my method i clear focus on all edittext's, then i just use requestFocus() on the button that was clicked...this way you dont need to create an invisible view for no reason

Answer (score 10):

I've successfully used the following in the onClick button code:

```java
editText.setEnabled(false);
editText.setEnabled(true);
```

Somewhat less complex than other methods...

Comment: In this case you just hide the keyboard, but cursor will still be at the EditText. Moreover onFocusChangedListener will not be called.

Answer (score 8):

The most elegant solution that I could find is this:

You can save this method in your utility class:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
   if (activity == null) return;
   if (activity.getCurrentFocus() == null) return;

   InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

By simply calling hideSoftKeyboad() method it will hide the keyboard but as you can see, the focus will still be present.

In order to remove the focus we will use a simple trick. Right above your input controls, add a dummy view like this:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/dummy"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

Then, write this line of code at the place where you call the focus-hiding method:

```
 theTextView.clearFocus();
```

Since the app needs to pass the focus to the next control it will be passed to our invisible view.

Comment: After trying lots of methods The bottom part of your answer solved the issue I was having. Thanks :) "Dummy View...Right above your input controls" specifically.

Answer (score 1):

How i solved it.

```
// xml file
<LinearLayout
...
android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"> // 1. make this focusableInTouchMode...
</LinearLayout>

// Activity file
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout; // 2. parent layout element
private Button mButton;

mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);

  mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLinearLayout.requestFocus(); // 3. request focus

            }
        });
```

I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

The top answer definitely works but would add a lot of unnecessary codes in my use case, where there are many buttons and every one of them will need a setOnClickListener code block to remove focus from the EditText.

Instead, my approach is to write a BindingAdapter to perform both focus change and the intended click action.

BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter("onClickWithFocusChange")
fun View.setOnClickWithFocusChangeListener(clickListener: View.OnClickListener?) {
    clickListener?.also {
        setOnClickListener(OnClickWithFocusChangeListener(it))
    } ?: setOnClickListener(null)
}

class OnClickWithFocusChangeListener(
    private val clickListener: View.OnClickListener
) : View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        v?.requestFocusFromTouch()
        clickListener.onClick(v)
        v?.clearFocus()
    }
}
```

In xml (databinding can now be used instead of programmatically setting every one of the clicklisteners):

```
<!-- parentview of the EditText -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ImageButton
    ...
    onClickWithFocusChange="@{() -> viewModel.buttonClicked()}"
    ... />
```

In activity/fragment:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
    if (!hasFocus) {
        requireContext().hideKeyboard(v)
        v.clearFocus()
    }
}
```

And lastly the extension function:

```
fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

Hope this helps some one!

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:hint="Enter your look-up here.." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="Search" />

</LinearLayout>
```

1. set `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the parent layout.
2. on button click transfer the focus to parent.

```
    binding.btn.setOnClickListener {
            binding.parent.requestFocus()
            // your stuff here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
private void hideDefaultKeyboard() {
    activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);//u have got lot of methods here
}
```

**EDIT:**

```java
LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
```

Comment: I can't import a WindowManager..?

Comment: I would have suggested to just add this to the button listener method: `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);` but that doesn't remove the keyboard. what I just said does work whenever I use it to remove focus when my app loads.

Comment: Somehow... WindowManager is red underlined and there is no Import suggestions.

Comment: The code works now, but unfortunetly does not hide the keyboard. It is still focused. I don't want the focus to be removed when the app loads first time. I want to remove it after a button is clicked.

Comment: call that method onclick of that button

Comment: remove the request focus, if any

Answer (score 0):

```
mTextView.setEnabled(!mTextView.isEnabled());
mTextView.setEnabled(!mTextView.isEnabled());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry late to the answer, but I hope this will be the right answer, as I fixed it using

```
try {
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (v != null) {
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
mEditText.setSelected(false);
mEditText.setFocusable(false);
mEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Write the following snippet on your button click.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just disable the EditText in the Button code? That should get rid of the keyboard and the focus.

edt_SearchDest.setEnabled(false);

Comment: then you can't focus on it *ever*; even when you touch it.