# EditText: Avoid getting focus on setText()

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have an activity with a scrollview containing  some buttons and a EditText
So the buttons are above the EditText component.

By clicking on a Button the EditText component change his text value by using `EditText.setText("foo");`

Unfortunately this call will set the focus to the EditText component, so the ScrollView will scroll to the EditText component (cursor blinks).

Is there a way to avoid this?

I have tried to do something like this

```
public void setText(String t){
    editText.setFocusable(false)
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    editText.setText(t);
    editText.setFocusable(true);
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}
```

But that does not work, and sometimes `setFocusable(true)` has no impact, so the EditText is not "clickable" anymore.

Comment: Try changing the focusability of EditText in xml.

Comment: But it should be still editable

Comment: try with setting textwatcher listener as null and then check.

Answer (score 2):

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

Called when this view wants to give up focus.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearFocus()

Comment: This is the most appropriate solution for the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your button use below code

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Refer the below link

[android edittext remove focus after clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414804/android-edittext-remove-focus-after-clicking-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

use this in your `xml` :

```
<EditText
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:cursorVisible="false" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
</EditText>
```

or

```
edittext.setKeyListener(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button use below code......

```
 InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

 inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```