# How can I let edittext losing focus when I clcik other regions?

Tags: android

I've seen similar problems at Google, but I just don't know how to do? This is my layout, and I set two edittext and a button. Edittext is used to input username and password. I want to close keyboard and let the button get focus when I click other regions on the screen. Now, when I click the button, it can't go to any Activity! I think this is because the button don't get focus. Am I right? Who can help me?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_user"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/login_picture" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_user_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_input_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/login_username"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/login_username" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#000000ff"
                android:hint="@string/login_username"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/devide_line" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_pwd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/login_username"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/login_password" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_pwd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#000000ff"
                android:hint="@string/login_pwd"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_user_info"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_btn"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set:

```
android:clickable="true" 
android:focusable="true" 
to other view and layout in your xml.
if you don't have result try to hidden keyboard

EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);
txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
hideKeyboard();
               // code to execute when EditText loses focus
            }
        }
    });
private void hideKeyboard() { 
// Check if no view has focus:
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
}
```

Comment: I just tried it, and it also doesn't work. I really don't know how to solve this problem!

Comment: @Kevin.Z Here (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) you can read about android:windowSoftInputMode= "adjustResize", "adjustPan", see whether you have something like that in manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the focus is the real issue, however you can try [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18415233/1945470) of code to remove the editext focus

EDIT: I modified the snippet link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18415233/1945470).

Comment: Er, It doesn't work... I don't know where is wrong.-_-#